# Print/debug GeoPoint Array

Tags: java, android, arrays, debugging, printing

I have a GeoPoint array list shown below:

```
ArrayList<GeoPoint> listOfPoints = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
```

and I would like to print it out to check that it correctly contains the points I have parsed into it.
I can only find how to print non GeoPoint arrays, 
any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: means you want to logout put of it

Comment: I've tried Log.i and log.println

Comment: System.pot.println(""+lst);

Comment: Still having issues unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, use the following line:

```
System.out.println(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have inserted the values as follows

```
ArrayList<GeoPoint> listOfPoints = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
Double latitude = Double.parseDouble("48.89364");
Double longitude = Double.parseDouble("2.33623");       
GeoPoint oneP = new GeoPoint((int)(latitude*1e6),(int)(longitude*1e6));
listOfPoints.add(oneP);
...
```

or you put the values from diferents `Location` objects.

```
GeoPoint oneP = new GeoPoint((int) (loc.getLatitude() * 1e6), (int) (loc.getLongitude() * 1e6));
listOfPoints.add(oneP);
...
```

The way to iterate and to print on the log is:

```
    for(GeoPoint gp:listOfPoints){
        Log.w(this.getClass().getName()+", Latitude", String.valueOf(gp.getLatitudeE6()/1e6));
        Log.w(this.getClass().getName()+", Longitude", String.valueOf(gp.getLongitudeE6()/1e6));
    }
```

`Log.w` is to print it as a WARNING on the logcat.